# Find UserUnit in a PDF file in c++

Tags: c++, pdf, pdf-reader

I need to get the UserUnit value from a PDF file with c++.

I'm able to do that in C# with the code below:

```
PdfReader reader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(filename);
for (int i = 1; i <= reader.NumberOfPages; i++)
{
    PdfDictionary pageDict = reader.GetPageN(i);
    PdfNumber userUnit = pageDict.GetAsNumber(PdfName.USERUNIT);
}
```

How can i do that in c++?

Comment: There's no standard c++ way to do it. You'll need to find some library that implemented that. However - asking for recommendations for libraries etc. is off-topic in StackOverflow.

Comment: There is a (visual studio) approach. You can use .Net dll's from managed C++ (C++/cli). 
See [.Net programming with C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp?view=msvc-170). Which would allow you to create an unmanaged wrapper class (that looks like a regular C++ class) and calls managed code.